# Xcode console print unnomal

Tags: xcode

My xcode console print unnomal,like this:

```
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x11cd46000)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x11cd5a000)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x11d043000)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x11d39d000)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x11d594000)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x11e179000)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x11e1c4000)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x11e294000)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x11e2a0000)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x11e2da000)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x11e39a000)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x11e3ba000)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x11e3dd000)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x11ea08000)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x11faf9000)
dyld_image_path_containing_address(0x11fb29000)
```

> _dyld_is_memory_immutable(0x10d950ba0, 36) dlopen(/usr/lib/system/introspection/libdispatch.dylib, 0x00000010)
>   dlopen(/usr/lib/system/introspection/libdispatch.dylib) ==>
>   0x1075a9c98 dlsym(0x1075a9c98, dispatch_introspection_versions)
>   dlsym(0x1075a9c98, dispatch_introspection_versions) ==> 0x10d5d8020
>   dlsym(0x1075a9c98, dispatch_introspection_hooks_install)
>   dlsym(0x1075a9c98, dispatch_introspection_hooks_install) ==>
>   0x10d5d6208 dlsym(0x1075a9c98, dispatch_get_current_queue)
>   dlsym(0x1075a9c98, dispatch_get_current_queue) ==> 0x10d5ac98a
>   dlsym(0x1075a9c98, dispatch_queue_get_label)   dlsym(0x1075a9c98,
>   dispatch_queue_get_label) ==> 0x10d5ae0b4 dlsym(0x1075a9c98,
>   dispatch_queue_offsets)   dlsym(0x1075a9c98, dispatch_queue_offsets)
>   ==> 0x10d5d7bd8

Comment: please look at [ask]

Answer (score 1):

You can disable Zombie Objects option to stop dyld_image_path_containing_address(...) console output.
To disable Zombie object, press **Option + Command + R** and select the "**Diagnostics**" tab. Finally, click "Enable Zombie Objects".